# Get the corresponding value based on created time

Tags: awk

```
cat input.txt | awk '/ID/;/TimeReceived/ {print $2,$3,$4}'
```

Output:

```
ID:    f7a570c2
03/26/14 18:22:50 GMT
ID:    f7f810a2
08/13/14 23:50:59 GMT
ID:    f8e76dd2
04/25/14 06:13:10 GMT
ID:    f92e90c2
03/19/14 12:51:23 GMT
ID:    f98ac152
08/01/14 00:10:43 GMT
ID:    faef4812
04/21/14 16:29:15 GMT
ID:    fb6b38d4
05/06/14 17:32:20 GMT
ID:    fbfb0d92
08/26/14 04:24:07 GMT
ID:    fc15d932
05/27/14 18:44:48 GMT
ID:    fc235e12
06/03/14 12:39:17 GMT
ID:    fc988622
06/23/14 16:02:29 GMT
ID:    fcb1e6c2
03/25/14 17:37:48 GMT
ID:    fd025382
05/28/14 16:50:29 GMT
ID:    fd061b12
04/21/14 18:41:41 GMT
ID:    fd7efde2
08/15/14 18:01:27 GMT
ID:    fdd30022
05/28/14 15:51:29 GMT
ID:    fdf73792
03/31/14 20:13:00 GMT
ID:    fe9d3a22
04/15/14 16:15:37 GMT
ID:    fea03cf2
08/04/14 02:06:00 GMT
ID:    ff7e3de2
07/07/14 10:51:41 GMT
```

The above output isn't sorted based on time. I want to extract all the "ID" which has the created time should be olderthan a month . can some one help me to code it ?

Comment: don't parse the output of cat command. You could change your command like this `awk '{...}' file`

Comment: What's the relationship between an `ID` line and a `TimeReceived` line? What, and how many, lines separate them? What does your raw file look like?

Comment: Raw file looks like this:

Comment: ID:    f7a570c2
TimeReceived: 03/26/14 18:22:50 GMT
ID:    f7f810a2
TimeReceived: 08/13/14 23:50:59 GMT
ID:    f8e76dd2
TimeReceived: 04/25/14 06:13:10 GMT

Comment: What actually I am looking for is, retrieve the "ID" value based on the created time (precisely the ID's which are created before one month)

Comment: Edit that into your question so formatting actually works. But it looks like you are just dropping the 'TimeReceived:' prefix from the timestamp lines?

Comment: Is there any way to print the output, both ID and Time received in a single Row. From there probably I can split the ID's based on created time

Comment: Can you bit explain what it basically does...Also can you please modify the above script to get only ID's have created before 30 days, as I could see some of the ID's listed with in the 30 days ...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk` and GNU `date` the following should work:

```
awk -vcutoff="$(date -d"-1 month" +%s)" '
/^ID:/ {
    ID=$2
    next
}

/^TimeReceived:/ {
    split($2, d, /\//)
    gsub(/:/, " ", $3)

    tm=mktime("20"d[3]" "d[1]" "d[2]" "$3)

    if (tm<cutoff) {
        print ID
    }
}' input
```

As per discussion in the comments some examples of how date does its calculations:

```
$ date -d "03/31/2014 - 1 month"
Mon Mar  3 00:00:00 EST 2014

$ date -d "06/26/2014 - 1 month"
Mon May 26 00:00:00 EDT 2014
```

The info page for `date` has a little more information about these calculations in section `28.6` `Relative items in date strings`.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. Not sure why I made that `ID` bit so complicated and I **always** screw up mktime's arguments... it doesn't help that the format in the source here is poor and I switch back and forth between `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY` all the time.

Comment: Any idea how `-1 month` works? Does it print the current day-of-the month in the previous month or does it print the date that occurred the number of days in the current month previously? Today is Aug 26 and `date -d"-1 month"` prints July 26th which is fine but July and Aug have the same number of days so that doesn't tell me anything. If today was June 26th would it print May 26th ("1 month earlier" or May 27th ("The number of days in June earlier")? What would it print if today was March 30? Hopefully it wouldn't print Feb 30 but would it print Feb 27 or something else?

Comment: January 31 + 1 month: result starts with Feb 31, then reconciles that to March 3rd (or 2nd depending on leap). So it increments the month, then adjusts the days to fit. Similarly "mar 30 - 1 month" = "mar 2"

Comment: Is that just a different way of saying it increments/decrements by the number of days in the current month or is there a subtle difference? Hang on: "Mar 30 - 1 month = mar 2"??? Say it's not so! I just tested it and you're right - that is bizarre. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit unfortunate how that works. Using a raw day count is better if you have a specific requirement and/or finding some other way to avoid the "fuzziness" (to use the info page's term) for how "month" and "year" work.

Comment: I'll say! You'd think a fundamental criteria for the "-1 month" calculation would be that the result couldn't be in the same month since the request is to subtract "1 month" not to subtract "95% of a month". Must've been a theoretical mathematician who came up with that one right after "proving" that 1 == 2 or something...

Comment: The info page specifically talks about the fuzziness in relation to getting "the previous month" and suggests that the reliable method is to ask for the month before a date [prior to the 15th of the current month](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand it's fuzzy but IMHO finding the same date the previous/next month and if it didn't exist then regressing to the last day of that month would have made much more sense. With that "Mar 30 - 1 month" = "Feb 28th" and "Jan 31 + 1 month" = "Feb 28th" which I think would be a much more reasonable and expected results than "Mar 2" and "Mar 3" respectively. I've never used this feature and never will, though, so I probably shouldn't get too excited about it's semantics :-).

Comment: Can you just explain if this script does show the all the ID's which have created a month older..rather than taking a month, can you adjust this script to take the ID's have created correctly 30 days older.

Comment: This script, barring the oddity of date's calculation of days (see the conversation above this), outputs the IDs from the previous month only. It does not take a month as argument. (It could easily be made to do so but does not at the moment.)